# using a multi-value Lookup field in a WHERE clause under ADODB

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb, lookup-tables

How do you select rows based on a multi-value Lookup field in an Access database?

The below ASP code returns no value when using multi-data column:

```
<%
Dim Contractors
Dim Contractors_cmd
Dim Contractors_numRows

Set Contractors_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Contractors_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Listings_STRING
Contractors_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Contractor WHERE UserStatus = 'Active' AND     AgentID= "& Session("AgentID") 
Contractors_cmd.Prepared = true

Set Contractors = Contractors_cmd.Execute
Contractors_numRows = 0
%>
```

Comment: I must admit it's a while since I used [tag:ms-access] and even longer since I dabbled with it for web development, but I've never heard of a *"multi-data"* column is that the term used in Microsoft Access? Do you mean a *"Lookup Field"*? If so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379369/692942) might be useful.

Comment: Yes Lookup Field sorry. The field is already created in the database but cant seem to have it shown. Not to sure if the select from code differs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `UserStatus` is a multi-value Lookup field then the individual value(s) of that field are accessed via `UserStatus.Value` so you'll need to use

```sql
... WHERE UserStatus.Value = 'Active' ...
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you please assist with the insert function into a multi-value field with two or three values?

Comment: @user3501463 That's a different question. Please start a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that.