# Ms-Access Dlookup format

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am new to access and I need help implementing a Dlookup function to call the associated value from a data sheet. I know how to run a perfect Vlookup in excel to solve this but I am lost for access.
The issue is that I would like to automatically call the Book_ID when the Name_of_Book is entered or selected from the list in Student_Data. Please see attached images. This is the formula that I am trying is `Book_ID:=DLookUp("Book_ID","Book_Data","Name_of_Book")`

[Student data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6zqY.png)

[image]

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZ0c.png)

[image]

Comment: Avoid lookup fields in tables as they hide the structure. Lookups should be done at query or form level. See [look-up-vs-relationship-microsoft-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379232/look-up-vs-relationship-microsoft-access) or [The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm).

Comment: I agree, I NEVER build lookups in table. So if you do have a Lookup with alias in table and are seeing book name, be aware the actual value in field is the Book_ID. Use a multi-column combobox or listbox on form to pull the Book_ID and Name_of_Book fields.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the advise guys. I will look into the suggestions and update you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got it to work by using a dynamic combo box on a form and used a macro to update the BOOK ID when a BOOK NAME is selected.